# Mvc textbox with Bootstrap Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I a using [Bootstrap validator](http://formvalidation.io/)  with MVC and not using any pattern but the text boxes are not accepting special characters.

Code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Line1, new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = 2})
```

Validation Code

```
.bootstrapValidator({
            excluded: [':disabled'],
            feedbackIcons: {

                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            // live: 'enabled',
            fields: {
               Line1: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Does your ViewModel property `Line1` have some attribute on it preventing special characters from being entered? Does this happen if you remove the Bootstrap validator?

Comment: Are the special characters HTML mark up or something that MVC may reject for security concerns? I could look up a reference link that spells out by default MVC rejects unencoded markup to protect your app from Cross Site scripting.

Comment: @KSib If I am removing the bootstrap validator it is working fine...

Comment: @Chad I don't think so, because If I am removing the bootstrap validator it is accepting special characters.

Comment: And which bootstrap validator are you using?

Comment: @KSib sorry this is the validator http://bootstrapvalidator.com

Comment: Where's the code for how you're hooking up your validator?

Comment: @KSib updated the question....